# Oracle - JSON Query select all

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c

On Oracle 12c, I have a table with a column containing a JSON string, there's no nested JSON data.

I would like to select all JSON data without having to specify each attribute and if the value is not a string cast it to string, is this possible?

```sql
SELECT
   jt.*
FROM
   my_table,
   JSON_TABLE ( my_json_col, '$'
         COLUMNS (
            row_number FOR ORDINALITY,
            phone_type VARCHAR2 ( 10 ) PATH '$.type',
            phone_num VARCHAR2 ( 20 ) PATH '$.number'
         )
      )
   AS jt
WHERE
   user = '83';
```

Example data:

```json
{
  "user_name": "Dave",
  "phone_number": "13326415",
  "married": false,
  "age": 18
}
```

Desired result:

```
user_name   phone_number   married   age
"Dave"      "13326415"     "false"   "18"
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to add some example data from your table, and your expected results?

Comment: @kfinity Added example data and expected results.

Comment: Not possible, for a very general reason (which applies to many other similar situations) - it will help you if you understand this. A "plain" SQL statement requires that the number of columns, their names and their order (and their data types) be known when the query is compiled, which is BEFORE the data is read from disk and processed. What you want is the opposite: decide what columns (even how many columns) the output will have only after the data is seen. Not possible with plain SQL. Possible with dynamic SQL, which is a much more advanced topic.

Comment: Before you go the "dynamic SQL" route, though - WHY do you need this? Why would you ever need to write a query that outputs columns which you don't know about in advance? What kind of business need is this? Generally a "need" like this suggests something is broken in the data model to begin with (long before you think about actual data content, or writing queries on it).

Answer (score 1):

There's no dynamic method by using a *plain* SQL Select statement but such a PL/SQL code block might be an option in order to display as desired

```sql
DECLARE
  v_js_data     my_table.my_json_col%TYPE;
  v_js_obj      JSON_OBJECT_T;
  v_js_obj_list JSON_KEY_LIST;
  v_title       VARCHAR(4000);
  v_value       VARCHAR(4000);  
BEGIN
  SELECT my_json_col INTO v_js_data FROM my_table WHERE user_id = 83;

  v_js_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE(v_js_data);
  v_js_obj_list := v_js_obj.get_keys;

  FOR c IN 1 .. v_js_obj_list.COUNT 
  LOOP
    v_title := v_title||RPAD(v_js_obj_list(c),20,' '); 
    v_value := v_value||RPAD(v_js_obj.GET_STRING(v_js_obj_list(c)),20,' '); 
  END LOOP;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_title);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_value);
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38b140a790e00641af8715f424656426)</kbd>