# Oracle select JSON column as key / value table

Tags: json, oracle, select, oracle12c

In Oracle 12c, having a column with JSON data in this format:

```json
{
  "user_name": "Dave",
  "phone_number": "13326415",
  "married": false,
  "age": 18
}
```

How can I select it in this format:

```
key                val
--------------     ----------
"user_name"        "Dave"
"phone_number"     "13326415"
"married"          "false"
"age"              "18"
```

Comment: Using just SQL, you can not get the JSON keys as a value. You would need to know the keys and use something like `JSON_TABLE` to get the values for each key. It is possible to get what you are looking for using PL/SQL using the `GET_KEYS` function of the `JSON_OBJECT_T` type

Comment: Just apply a few manipulations to the provided answer for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841305/oracle-json-query-select-all) such as [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d9e1444cb37816cfca0b3d11bc266f07) (*I can't answer as the question being marked as duplicate*)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment, there is no way to get the keys of a JSON object using just SQL. With PL/SQL you can create a pipelined function to get the information you need. Below is a very simple pipelined function that will get the keys of a JSON object and print the type each key is, as well as the key name and the value.

First, you will need to create the types that will be used by the function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE key_value_table_rec FORCE AS OBJECT
(
    TYPE VARCHAR2 (100),
    key VARCHAR2 (200),
    VALUE VARCHAR2 (200)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE key_value_table_t AS TABLE OF key_value_table_rec;
/
```

Next, create the pipelined function that will return the information in the format of the types defined above.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_key_value_table (p_json CLOB)
    RETURN key_value_table_t
    PIPELINED
AS
    l_json           json_object_t;
    l_json_keys      json_key_list;
    l_json_element   json_element_t;
BEGIN
    l_json := json_object_t (p_json);
    l_json_keys := l_json.get_keys;

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_json_keys.COUNT
    LOOP
        l_json_element := l_json.get (l_json_keys (i));
        PIPE ROW (key_value_table_rec (
                      CASE
                          WHEN l_json_element.is_null THEN 'null'
                          WHEN l_json_element.is_boolean THEN 'boolean'
                          WHEN l_json_element.is_number THEN 'number'
                          WHEN l_json_element.is_timestamp THEN 'timestamp'
                          WHEN l_json_element.is_date THEN 'date'
                          WHEN l_json_element.is_string THEN 'string'
                          WHEN l_json_element.is_object THEN 'object'
                          WHEN l_json_element.is_array THEN 'array'
                          ELSE 'unknown'
                      END,
                      l_json_keys (i),
                      l_json.get_string (l_json_keys (i))));
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        CASE SQLCODE
            WHEN -40834
            THEN
                --JSON format is not valid
                NULL;
            ELSE
                RAISE;
        END CASE;
END;
/
```

Finally, you can call the pipelined function from a SELECT statement

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE (get_key_value_table (p_json => '{
  "user_name": "Dave",
  "phone_number": "13326415",
  "married": false,
  "age": 18
}'));

      TYPE             KEY       VALUE
__________ _______________ ___________
string     user_name       Dave
string     phone_number    13326415
boolean    married         false
number     age             18
```

If your JSON values are stored in a column in a table, you can view the keys/values using `CROSS JOIN`

```sql
WITH
    sample_table (id, json_col)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, '{"key1":"val1","key_obj":{"nested_key":"nested_val"},"key_bool":false}'
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, '{"key3":3.14,"key_arr":[1,2,3]}' FROM DUAL)
SELECT t.id, j.*
  FROM sample_table t CROSS JOIN TABLE (get_key_value_table (p_json => t.json_col)) j;

   ID       TYPE         KEY    VALUE
_____ __________ ___________ ________
    1 string     key1        val1
    1 object     key_obj
    1 boolean    key_bool    false
    2 number     key3        3.14
    2 array      key_arr
```